# Are rewrite providers supported inside ASP.NET core?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I know you can have rewrite middleware but I have my database where all rewrite rules are set up and I use this code that used to work inside .net framework. Is this supported in .NET core. What is solution?

```
 <rewrite>
    <providers>
      <provider name="FileMap" type="DbProvider, Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f">
      <settings>
        <add key="ConnectionString" value="myconnString" />
        <add key="StoredProcedure" value="Search.GetRewriteUrlMvc" />
        <add key="CacheMinutesInterval" value="0" />
      </settings>
    </provider>
  </providers>
  <!--<rules configSource="rewrite-rules-sol-local.config" />-->
  <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps-sol.config" />
</rewrite>
```

Comment: You can implement `IRule` interface to read rules from the database, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#irule-based-rule

Comment: Yes, I know that but didn't want to do that before find out if it supported. If not, then I will create IRule

Comment: IIS rewrite providers are Windows/.NET Framework only, so impossible to be supported by ASP.NET Core (which runs cross platform).

Comment: Yes, but since app will always be run on IIS and windows I tought that there might be some solution for this scenario where we know that will remain running on IIS

Comment: If you set the scope to IIS only, then clearly it has been discussed in the past, https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/309